# Why does eval "$BASH_COMMAND" crash bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, crash

If you run `eval "$BASH_COMMAND"` in the terminal, it will crash and the terminal window will disappear. I have not been able to understand why this particular command crashes `bash`.

The strange thing is that when I run `echo "$BASH_COMMAND"`, this happens:

```
$ echo "$BASH_COMMAND"
echo "$BASH_COMMAND"
```

Another thing is that `$BASH_COMMAND` does not have a value:

```
"$BASH_COMMAND"
bash: "$BASH_COMMAND": command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$BASH_COMMAND` does have a value: the current command being executed. This is useful in situations like a `trap` handler, so the handler can find out what command was executing when the trap triggered. But when you use `$BASH_COMMAND` as part of a regular command, things get weird and circular and confusing. Let's look at the examples you gave:

- `echo "$BASH_COMMAND"`

  In this example, the value of the `BASH_COMMAND` variable is exactly the string `echo "$BASH_COMMAND"`, so when the shell parses the command line it expands the variable reference giving the equivalent of:

  ```
  echo 'echo "$BASH_COMMAND"'
  ```

  Note: the single quotes there aren't really part of the command, they're just something I added to indicate that that part of the command should not undergo variable expansion, double-quote removal, etc. In the real command, those shouldn't be done because *they already have* been done. Anyway, the result is that the string gets printed literally, giving the result you saw.
- `"$BASH_COMMAND"`

  Again, the value of `BASH_COMMAND` is exactly the string `"$BASH_COMMAND"`, so after expansion it's the equivalent of:

  ```
  '"$BASH_COMMAND"'
  ```

  ...and there isn't a command by that name, so you get an error to that effect.

  (Actually, quotes and dollar signs are allowed in unix filenames, so you could name a script that and put it somewhere in your `PATH`, and then that *would* be a valid command name. I don't particularly recommend doing this.)
- `eval "$BASH_COMMAND"`

  This one's more complicated. The value of `BASH_COMMAND` is the string `eval "$BASH_COMMAND"`, so after expansion it's the equivalent of:

  ```
  eval 'eval "$BASH_COMMAND"'
  ```

  But what the `eval` command does is take its argument and run it as a shell command, including all the usual parsing. So, it runs the command:

  ```
  eval "$BASH_COMMAND"
  ```

  ...which expands `$BASH_COMMAND` again, resulting in:

  ```
  eval 'eval "$BASH_COMMAND"'
  ```

  ...which makes the `eval` command parse and run:

  ```
  eval "$BASH_COMMAND"
  ```

  ...and this loop continues forever. Or rather, it eventually runs out of some resource (probably stack space) as it tries to keep track of this ever-expanding thing. Apparently this causes a poorly-handled crash.

  But whatever the details are, that command cannot possibly work. It requests the shell to perform an infinite series of tasks, and that cannot end successfully.